# Setting notifications at different times in android

Tags: android

I have an android app.I want to produce five notifications at five different times which are setted by the user.The notifications should produced if my app will not be running...How can I do this?

In the below class I am comparing the db notification values with the devices time in an infinite while loop in oncreate().res1,res2...res5 are the five notification times stored in the db.day4 is the system time...

MyService.java

```
ppublic class MyService extends Service {
              private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MYPRAYER.db";   
              private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notification";
              String tag="TestService";
                String a="hello";
                String res1,res2,res3,res4,res5;
                int hour,minute;
                String day3,day4,minute1,hour1;
                MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
                   /* Service creation */
               @Override
               public void onCreate() {
             super.onCreate();
               Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
               Log.i(tag, "Service created...");


                  /* Rereive notification times from the databse notificaion */
              SQLiteDatabase myDB;
            myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            String[] resultColumns = new String[] {"fajr","zuhr","asr","magrib","isha"};
            Cursor allRows = myDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, resultColumns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            Integer cindex = allRows.getColumnIndex("fajr");
            Integer cindex1 = allRows.getColumnIndex("zuhr");
            Integer cindex2 = allRows.getColumnIndex("asr");
            Integer cindex3 = allRows.getColumnIndex("magrib");
            Integer cindex4 = allRows.getColumnIndex("isha");
            allRows.moveToFirst();
            res1=allRows.getString(cindex);
            res2=allRows.getString(cindex1);
            res3=allRows.getString(cindex2);
            res4=allRows.getString(cindex3);
            res5=allRows.getString(cindex4);


            myDB.close();

            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
            try 
            {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Rereive calender date
                hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // Take hour from the calender
                minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);    // Take minute from the calender
                minute1=minute + "";  // Convert minute to dtring
                if(minute1.equals("1")) 
                {
                minute1="01";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("2"))
                {
                minute1="02";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("3"))
                {
                minute1="03";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("4"))
                {
                minute1="04";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("5"))
                {
                minute1="05";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("6"))
                {
                minute1="06";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("7"))
                {
                minute1="07";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("8"))
                {
                minute1="08";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("9"))
                {
                minute1="09";
                }
                     /* Converting to 12 hour format */
                if ( hour < 12 )
                {
                     hour=hour;
                     day3=hour + "" + ":" + minute1;
                     day4=day3 + " " + "AM"; // DAY4 Contains the system time
                }
                else
                {
                    hour=hour-12;
                    day3=hour + "" + ":" + minute1;
                    day4=day3 + " " + "PM";
                }



                if(day4.equals(res1))
              {
                     Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");


              }



                 if(day4.equals(res2))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  }


                 if(day4.equals(res3))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  } 
                 if(day4.equals(res4))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  }
                 if(day4.equals(res5))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  }

               Thread.sleep(1000);
       } 
       catch (InterruptedException e)
       {
               Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
               //System.out.println("New 1 Exception here");

       }

       catch (Exception e)
      {
               //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
           System.out.println("nEW Exception here");
      }          
       }

       }         
          @Override
          public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
          super.onStart(intent, startId);  
          Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
       }
         @Override
         public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

         @Override
         public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return null;
        }

         private  void Notification(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage)
       {
         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "A New Message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

         notification.setLatestEventInfo(MyService.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
         notificationManager.notify(10001, notification);
   //HELLO_ID++;
         Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); 

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      try
      {
      mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);

      AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(
                                  Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      int volumen = audioManager.getStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

      if (volumen != 0) {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
      }
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {  
          System.out.println("Exception here");
          //System.out.println("Exception 1 here");
      }
      }
          }
```

Logcat:

07-27 16:25:00.542: I/TestService(363): Service created...
07-27 16:25:20.752: I/dalvikvm(363): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-27 16:25:20.803: I/dalvikvm(363): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Answer (score 0):

What I did was use `AlarmManager` that triggers a `BroadcastReceiver` to set the notification. So search that on the Android docs. There are also a lot of resources on that stuff. Others might also tell you not to use `BroadcastReceiver`, but rather use a `Service`. To be honest it can go both ways, so whatever choice you make should be fine. As for notification, you can easily google notifications to find resources on that. Search Status Notifications.

Comment: I have run my app.The notification in my app is sceduled in a service by comparing the db stored values with the devices time ...But notification is not running properly...device is forceclose just after some seconds.But notification is didplayed with the forceclose....What is the prolbem I have....

Comment: You need to post what the error is. I can't help unless I see that. It would also help if I see your class that implements `Service`.